# SlickGrid - Selecting a Row without custom controls

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I need functionality in the application to allow users click on a row to select a row. Additionally I would want to add features for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + click to select a row.

I saw the examples where checkboxes are added to each row to select a row. I do not wish to add such checkboxes to the application.

I came across a link which is a year old but seems to answer my question http://groups.google.com/group/slickgrid/browse_thread/thread/96a5291161d41efa

Is there is a better way of doing things here?

Comment: What do you want to do with "selected" table-row elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SlickGrid DOM is *NOT* static - please avoid modifying it directly.

This functionality is already built into SlickGrid via a pluggable SelectionModel.  There are two selection models included in the distro - Slick.CellSelectionModel and Slick.RowSelectionModel.  All you have to do is call

> grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());

See http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html for an example.

Comment: Hi Tin, I cann't find RowSelectionModel() function when execute this [new Slick.RowSelectionModel()]. Do you has any ideas?

Comment: Stiger, you'll probably need to add `<script src="slick.rowselectionmodel.js"></script>` to your header after the slick.grid.js script

Comment: a slightly updated canonical link is https://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html

Answer (score 1):

That's an 83Kb file (just the JS), which isn't horrible but is pretty large for what you are trying to do.

```
//select the parent table element, then select its child (the `tbody` element) then get its children which will be the `tr` elements
$('table').children().children().on('click', function (event) {

    //check to see if ctrl+shift is being held while this click occured
    if (event.ctrlKey === true && event.shiftKey === true) {

        //if ctrl+shift were held during the click then you know this element has been selected
        //and you can do what you need, in this demo I'm just adding a class to denote that the element has been selected
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

As you can see, if all you want to do is test if `ctrl+shift` were held-down while clicking on the `tr` element then you can use a lot less than 83KB of code (the above demo is 600 bytes).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YZytJ/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Hi Jasper, Thanks for the prompt response. The basic concern I have here is that there are some basic assumptions in the solution made around the structure of the Grid (in this case table). If for some reason the structure changes (or some Renderer's are added) there could be an issue. So do we know if we have something out-of-the-box for slickgrid?

I have an HTML Table control in my application I would certainly put the solution you provided to use in that control.

-Yazad Khambata

Comment: I can't comment on the `slickgrid` plugin, I've never used it. However it most likely uses a HTML structure that remains at least somewhat static. You can use your developer tools to inspect the DOM and figure out what HTML structure `slickgrid` is creating.

Comment: Thanks again Jasper...
I have inspected the dom structure of SlickGrid and the structure is based on DIVs. I think based on the example you shared, I should be able to juxtapose that for SlickGrid but yes, still would be very happy If I got a solution or pointer from someone to a more SlickGrid specific ou-of-the-box solution. :)